# Customizing an OFfice 365 Sharepoint website with CSS

Tags: css, sharepoint, office365

I would like to customize a website hosted on Office 365. For example, I would like to do something as simple as changing the font size on all the pages of the wiki.

I haven't found an option of editing the website CSS in the Site Settings. How can this be done?

(I guess I'll have to edit the current theme or to add a new theme, but I haven't found a guide to do any of these).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might get more answers to this on http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3):

You can upload a custom CSS file to the Style Library. Then in Site Settings > Look and Feel > Master page, set the Alternate CSS URL to your file.

Comment: Thanks, Rich. But I don't have a Master Page item in the Look and Feel section. What should I do?

Comment: That menu item only appears when the Publishing features are enabled. However, there is nothing publishing specific about that page, so you can try navigating to it directly at something like: http://yoursite/_layouts/ChangeSiteMasterPage.aspx

Comment: Is there a difference between Sharepoint Online and Sharepoint 365? I'm not the admin, so I know very little about Sharepoint other than I hate the wiki features compared to Confluence.  Styling has become not just a pain point, but an impediment.